# TYPO3 CMS : tx_news : How can I change the labels in List View?

Tags: translate, label, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

--

Hello!

I use TYPO3 CMS 6.2.9 and the Versatile News System (tx_news).
For my User (Editor), I'll only allow to add new news records in my specific sys-folder. Here's my pageTSconfig for the sys-folder:

```
### only for EDITORS usergroup 2
[usergroup = 2]
  # only show "new news and news tag" for a new data record
  mod.web_list {
    allowedNewTables = tx_news_domain_model_news, tx_news_domain_model_tag
  }
[GLOBAL]
```

It works.

**But how can I translate the labels, for example in german: "Artikel" and "Nachrichten-Tag" in List-View for my Editor**. I can't find these strings in Ext. news folder (typo3config/ext/news). In this case, I'll use tx_news not for NEWS, so it won't confuse my backend-user (editor) ;)

I#m talking about this List View:

[image]

I can translate all other labels via TCEFORM

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.title.label.de = Überschrift
```

but not the labels at list view.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _In this case, I'll use tx_news not for NEWS, so it won't confuse my backend-user (editor)_ what do you mean ? use news not for NEWS?

Comment: Here is my example live: http://esa-survey.de/de/ergebnisse/querschnitt.html   the contentis not really "news" but I use tx_news to handle the data records in backend and frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These labels are configured in TCA for given table and only way to override it is changing it's value i.e. by adding this line to `typo3conf/extTables.php`

```
$TCA['tx_news_domain_model_news']['ctrl']['title'] = 'Change me...';
```

Problem with this is you can't do it conditionally by default, maybe this EXT will help you (as mentioned on some forum it's not maintained anymore)

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tcamanipulate/

How to find it: Every table has its TCA (required) so you can find it with editor, or using SYSTEM > Configuration module to browse currently loaded TCA.

Comment: How did you find out this code line? It works for the title! "$TCA['tx_news_domain_model_tags']['ctrl']['title'] = 'Change me, too..';" - it's for the news tags. Thank you very much. I can change the labels from the other TCA fields by pageTSconfig. Not necessary to use an (old) Ext. Thanks!